# Abort a slow flush to disk after write?

Tags: python, linux, file-io, flush

Is there a way to abort a python write operation in such a way that the OS doesn't feel it's necessary to flush the unwritten data to the disc?

I'm writing data to a USB device, typically many megabytes. I'm using 4096 bytes as my block size on the write, but it appears that Linux caches up a bunch of data early on, and write it out to the USB device slowly. If at some point during the write, my user decides to cancel, I want the app to just stop writing immediately. I can see that there's a delay between when the data stops flowing from the application, and the USB activity light stops blinking. Several seconds, up to about 10 seconds typically. I find that the app is holding in the close() method, I'm assuming, waiting for the OS to finish writing the buffered data. I call flush() after every write, but that doesn't appear to have any impact on the delay. I've scoured the python docs for an answer but have found nothing.

Comment: This is completely OS- and filesystem-dependent.  The "correct" behavior (under normal, async mounting) is for close() to return immediately; it should only wait to flush if you explicitly fdatasync().  You're not likely to find a portable way to change this behavior, since it'll vary wildly across systems.  (Since XP or so, Windows doesn't even write cache to USB drives at all by default.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat filesystem dependent, but in some filesystems, if you delete a file before (all of) it is allocated, the IO to write the blocks will never happen. This might also be true if you truncate it so that the part which is still being written is chopped off.

Not sure that you can really abort a write if you want to still access the data. Also the kinds of filesystems that support this (e.g. xfs, ext4) are not normally used on USB sticks.

If you want to flush data to the disc, use fdatasync(). Merely flushing your IO library's buffer into the OS one will not achieve any physical flushing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I am understanding this correct, you want to be able to 'abort' and NOT flush the data. This IS possible using a ctype and a little pokery. This is very OS dependent so I'll give you the OSX version and then what you can do to change it to Linux:

```
f = open('flibble1.txt', 'w')
f.write("hello world")
import ctypes
x = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/lib/libc.dylib')
x.close(f.fileno())
try:
  del f
catch IOError:
  pass
```

If you change /usr/lib/libc.dylib to the libc.so.6 in /usr/lib for Linux then you should be good to go. Basically by calling close() instead of fclose(), no call to fsync() is done and nothing is flushed.

Hope that's useful.

Comment: Lee, this looks like it should work, however, I could not get the desired behavior. I called x.close(f.fileno()) and it still performed the flush, blocking on the close() call, exactly like the python close() command.

Comment: If that happened then .close() didn't actually get called. You can check by checking the return code. If you get None, or a number, it didn't work - if you get 0 (zero) then it did.

Answer (score 1):

When you abort the write operation, trying doing `file.truncate(0);` before closing it.